# ADF DB connection and sessions

Tags: oracle-adf

I have 1 application module, 1 connection to DB and two DataControls based on a single ViewObject. They are placed on the same form. Is it any possibility that ADF makes 2 sessions when I insert data to first DataControl and trying to re-execute query in second?

Comment: What is the current behavior and what do you want to achieve (in practical terms)? Do you want to insert data from both DC by pressing only one button or what?

Comment: I have problem in runtime. Two users working with application. In DB i have packages with global variables. In theory first user works with his own variables, change them and second user works with his own. But second user saw values from first user instead of default values. I think this problem goes from adf when using same AppModule instance in trying to economy resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yours is not practically a problem. It is the way it should work. Two users cannot update/change the same row in the same time. The first that Commits the change is OK whereas to the second an Error popup will be displayed telling him that the current row has been updated from someone else. If the users are not working (changing) the same row but different rows of the same ViewObject then you should consider this link:

http://radio-weblogs.com/0118231/stories/2004/03/24/whyDoIGetOraclejborowinconsistentexception.html

I suggest you take a look also to this book, you can find it free to download, just search a bit.

[http://www.amazon.com/Quick-Start-Oracle-Fusion-Development/dp/0071744282](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071744282)

Have a nice day, tung.